# String.format() statement for spacing each line only spaces braces

Tags: java, regex

I am attempting to utilize the `String.format()` method to prepend a variable number of spaces to each line from an *infile* to produce a new *outfile*. The *infile* is a .java file with all whitespace removed with the exception of newlines, and each brace has it's own line.

This is my code where I test to add 3 spaces before every line. Note the `Scanner` argument comes from `main` where it takes the *infile*:

```
void printToOutFile(Scanner s, File o) throws IOException {
    FileWriter stream = new FileWriter(o);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(stream);
    int numOfSpaces = 3;

    while(s.hasNext()) {
        line = s.nextLine();
        String l = String.format("%1$" + numOfSpaces + "s", line);
        out.write(l + "\n");
    }
    out.close()
}
```

The `String.format()` here seems to only add spaces before any braces, but not lines with text. I can't figure out why it would do that.

Comment: could you share your current output and your expected output?

Comment: Dillon has answered my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying a width in your format string, but I don't that that's doing exactly what you want. From the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) docs:

> The optional *width* is a non-negative decimal integer indicating the minimum number of characters to be written to the output.

Try this:

```
String l = String.format("%1$" + (numOfSpaces + line.length()) + "s", line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
format("%*s", numSpaces, line);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.